# Why does this (javascript) closure fail?

Tags: closures, qunit

The variable "called" is false when is should be set to true.. why is that?
It is set to true when called by the plugin but outside the closure it remains false.
Its a bit baffling. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
(function() {
    module("when InitializedApplication() is called");
    test("it should call the success function", function () {
    // arrange
    $("#qunit-fixture").append(
        '<script id="events-catalog-view-template"' +
        '        type="text/html"'+
        '        src="_events-catalog.view.html">' +
        '</script>' +
        '<div id="events-catalog-view-container"' +
        '     data-bind="template: {' +
        '             name="events-catalog-view-template" ' +
        '             afterRender="tpw.mediator.eventscatalog.setupViewDataBinding" ' +
        '          }"' + 
        '</div>'
    );              

    var called = false;

    // act
    var init = TPW.InitializeApplication();

    init({
        logLevel: "debug",
        success: function (successfullResolution) {                               
            called = true;
        },
        error: function (failedResolution) {                            
        }
    });

    // assert                
    ok(called, "success function called");
    });    
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The qunit `ok()` function was being called before the success callback. Async problem.